# How do I repeat fadeIn(duration: NSTimeInterval method indefinitely?

Tags: swift

I have this extension that I'm using as a blinker effect. It fades out and in but only once.

1. How do I repeat it?
2. How do I repeat it until user input? IBAction below extension.

   ```
   extension UIView {
   func fadeIn(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0, completion: ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
   UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
       self.alpha = 1.0
       }, completion: completion)  }

   func fadeOut(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0, delay: NSTimeInterval = 0.0, completion: (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
   UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: delay, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {
       self.alpha = 0.0
       }, completion: completion)
   }
   }
   ```

Separate IBAction

```
@IBAction func SendAge(sender: AnyObject) {


    let newAge = String(inputField.text!)

    if ((inputField.text?.isEmpty) != false) {

        self.sentence.blink()
        self.sentence.text = "Enter a number!"
        self.sentence.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    else {
        sentence.text = "Oh, you're \(newAge)"
        return()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple approach:

```
extension UIView {

    func blink(duration: NSTimeInterval = 1.0) {
        self.alpha = 1
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0,
            options: [.CurveEaseIn, .Autoreverse, .Repeat], animations: {
                self.alpha = 0
            }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

To cancel it, just set the view's `alpha` back to 1.

Comment: are you saying i dont need any of that code above in my extension? lol

Comment: sorry, how do i call this in my IBAction above? `self.sentence.blink(NSTimeInterval)...`??

Comment: OK so I got it working. New code in edit above. Thanks. But right now I'm trying to make it stop. I guess I can make my else statement an else if and add the cancel there?

Comment: Yes, presumably you want to set `self.sentence.alpha = 1` in the else clause.

Comment: Done. Thank you Rob. Man I wish I could hire you as a 3hr/week email tutor. I've seen you around. If I didn't know any better I'd think you were the creator of Swift :) You take Paypal? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method on `NSTimer` `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(interval: NSTimeInterval, target:, selector, userInfo:, repeats: bool)` which you can set to true and this will run as long as the timer is running.

Comment: Yes I've seen the method everywhere but where do I create it in the extension? Do I create it twice i.e. once below each of my functions or as a new separate function under both functions? Then in my IBAction how do I call it make the timer to stop at the same time?